# How do I edit the data/content inside a wordpress theme?

Tags: content

Im new to word-press, I have purchased a theme, and imported it with its demo data, how do I now edit the actual content of the website, and replace the demo data?

I have tried going on the 'Pages' option and clicking on a certain page, then the various options including 'classic mode', 'frontend editor' and 'wpbakery page builder'.

They all seem to be designed to change the styling as oppose to actually changing the data/content of the website.

Comment: What is actually wrong with my question? Nothing. I need help and there is nowhere to get it.

Comment: Have you asked the theme developer? How the demo data is stored and edited is something you’d need to ask them, if it’s not standard. 3rd party themes are off topic here.

Comment: Rhys, what theme did you purchase? If you can post that I am happy to see if I can help you find the documentation you need.

Comment: Hi @Faye the theme is http://preview.themeforest.net/item/fixar-phone-repair-theme/full_screen_preview/21276915?_ga=2.128448971.639241033.1557514449-1693698128.1557514449

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down your [theme documentation](http://fixar.templines.org/documentation/index.html).

I think the section you'll be wanting to check out is the **"Page Builder"** section, which has links to the **wpbakery page builder documentation and tutorials** that will help you out. That should get you going. If you have purchased the theme within the last 6 months, you should also be able to ask for some help through their [support forum](http://support.templines.com/).

I hope that helps you get going.